# How to store ledger data some persistent stoage location in AWS setup

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have set up hyperledger fabric network in aws using three ec2 instance. I want to store the ledger data and couchdb data some persistence location where I can get it if the AWS ec2 instance destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map the docker content outside the docker.

The ledger content for an orderer is inside **/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/**.
The ledger content for a peer is inside **/var/hyperledger/production/**.

The idea is that, first of all, you create a folder, let's call it "**ledgers**".
Next, you will map content from the folders mentioned before inside that folder.
You can do this by adding to the docker-compose.yaml file the following volumes:

For orderer:

```
volumes:
   - ./ledgers/orderer1.example.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/
```

For peers:

```
volumes:
   - ./ledgers/peer1.example.com/:/var/hyperledger/production/
```

Now start your containers and you'll see that here inside you will find ledger content.
You have correctly mapped the production content of a running docker outside of it.
This folder is now on your local machine and you can share it however you want with your other AWS machines, from here it will be easy to set-up.